# May I send MsgBox message for all users who has the same .xlsm file open from sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online

We are using .xlsm files stored on sharepoint which need to be updated regularly. I would like to inform all users about macro starts/ends running who has the file open. Would be great to simply add a MsgBox to the VBA code but as I tested it is visible only for that user who starts the macro. 
Is there any solution to inform other users?

Many Thanks,
marci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xls macros runs on local system and it is not connected to another users machine. You have to think of sending notifications to other users... may be send email or something..

Comment: I see. It is an unfortunate situation in this case because it should be an on-time action - this is why I tried to use MsgBox instead of email. Anyway, I really apprichiate your help, many thanks for that

Comment: Yes...macro is not meant for that...please upvote and mark as answer if it was helpful.